# Request Count occurrences

Tags: mongodb, count, request

Here is an example of my MongoDB database in screenshot:

[image: I'm trying to create a request]
I'm trying to create a request which count numbers of actors per owner.login in my movies collection.

The result should be like this for all my Objects, from "movies" collection:

```
henry.tom       total_actors : 1
tercik.comip    total_actors : 9
```

Comment: This should help. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#use-in-group-stage

Comment: Thank you but I don't understand how to match it with my database :-/

Comment: Np. You don't even need `$group`. You can simply use `$project`. Something like `db.getCollection('movies').aggregate([ {"$project": { login:"$owner.login", "total_actors": {"$size": "$actors"}}} ])`. Please replace the image with text version of your documents in the post.

Comment: Thats great ! it works ! Cheers mate ! :)